# can anyone explain how 0x protocol swap tokens on contract level?

Tags: solidity, 0x

I am building a middleware contract to interact with 0x. but I can't find which function to use in the 0x contract. could anyone help me?
can anyone explain how 0x swap tokens on contract level?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are building your own middleware, consider looking at the [0x protocol docs](https://protocol.0x.org/en/latest/), specifically the [architecture overview](https://protocol.0x.org/en/latest/architecture/overview.html) section could be helpful to understand how all the smart contracts in the protocol interact.

Also, https://github.com/0xProject/protocol contains the 0x protocol smart contracts.

However, if you'd like to use our existing API, here's some useful docs:

- https://0x.org/docs/api
- https://0x.org/docs/